# how to strip php tags from textarea?

Tags: php

I am trying to remove  tags from a textarea.

I open a php page in a textarea successfully using the code bellow but I only want the code to be there and remove the `<?php` from the top of the page and `?>` from the bottom of the page in the textarea.

this is my php code for loading the php page:

```
<?php

$fn = "phpPage.php";

if (isset($_POST['content']))

{

    $content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);

    $fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");


    fputs($fp,$content);

    fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");

}

?>
```

**and this is how i load the page in the textarea:**

```
<textarea id="code"  style="width:450px;"  rows="25" cols="50" name="content"><?php readfile($fn); ?></textarea>
```

I tried this and it didn't work without giving me any error:

```
strip_tags($fn, '<?php ?>');
```

could someone please advise on this?

Thanks

EDIT: I've tried all the suggestions and none worked so far.

Comment: "remove the from the bottom" wat?

Comment: `strip_tags() ` is what you need as far as I can understand. `$content = stripslashes($_POST['content']); $content = strip_tags($content);` etc.

Comment: you could try to wrap the textarea in `<pre><textarea></textarea</pre>` tags

Comment: strip_tags will not work on a filename. (or actually it will, but not how you intend it to).

Answer (score 0):

see this for an inspiration

```
$string = "SO.ME.TE.XT";
$string = str_replace(".","",$string);
echo($string);
```

will return "SOMETEXT". Hence

```
$string = YOUR PHP CODE;
$string = str_replace("<?php","",$string);
$string = str_replace("?>","",$string);
echo($string);
```

Should work in your case.

**Update 1:**

Another approach would be using jquery and a simple replace script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var codeContents = $("#code").val();
    $("#code").val(codeContents.replace("<?php","").replace("?>",""));
});
```

Comment: this will work if i put the code directly in the $string = YOUR PHP CODE; but I am loading a php "file" so how would i need to go about it?

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a simple javascript solution to your problem.

Comment: nice, but there is a syntax error in your code online 3!

Comment: I've tested the code and it works. Heres the JSFiddle for it :) http://jsfiddle.net/JKurcik/wr7s6/

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to do it in php.
There are ways to read content of a `.php` file:-

```
-> highlight_string(file_get_contents($fn));

-> readfile($fn);

-> $Vdata = file_get_contents($fn);
   $abc = var_dump($Vdata);
```

But these can only read the content and also these functions are not returning the output, so that we can assign them to any variable and can use them as per our wish.
We can just print/display the content of a `.php` file..

Well, the `Jquery` code shared by "JKurcik" can work for you but the issue you are facing becuase you are using that code in your `.php` file***(NOTE: In a .php file whenever or wherever we put "`<?php"`, it starts considering the start of php code)***.
You can make this working by adding that code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var codeContents = $("#code").val();
    $("#code").val(codeContents.replace("<?php","").replace("?>",""));
});
```

in a seperate `custom.js` file and call that js file in your `.php` doc, then it'll work for sure.